# Percentage of various Floating Point Operations in SPEC CPU Benchmarks

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, fortran, benchmarking

I am looking at the SPEC CPU2006 benchmark website for floating-point: [SPEC 2006 Floating Point](https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/CFP2006/)

I noticed that all of the benchmarks are listed but I couldn't find any information in regards to the percentage of basic floating point operations such as add/sub, mult, sqrt, div, etc.

How would I go about finding this information? That is, what is the % of add/sub, mults, divs, sqrts, etc for each benchmark?

As an example, the LINPACK benchmark has the following paper which includes operation counts: [The LINPACK Benchmark: Past, Present, and Future](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/PAPERS/hpl.pdf)

Comment: The LINPACK benchmark is based on a relatively simple, easily analyzed, operation, solving a dense system of linear equations. The SPEC benchmarks are based on complete applications and are much harder to analyze.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, well is there any published paper that mentions the percentage breakup for adds, mults, divs, etc. for some typical floating point workloads?

Comment: It is highly variable. Your best option is to pick workloads of interest to you, and search for "XXX flops" where "XXX" is the name of your workload. For example "fft flops"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some details in some random papers I happened to be browsing:

1. [Design issues in division and other floating-point operations by Oberman, S.F.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=565590)
2. [Reconfigurable Custom Floating-Point Instructions by Jin et. al](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=115374)

These papers plot the relative frequency of multiply, add, subtract, divide, and square root.